# How to create a pop up contact form that return success message in the place of the send button?

Tags: php, html

I have HTML pop up a contact form that I need help with to return a success message on the page or in the place of the send button.

```
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
   <form id="myForm" action="action_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-container">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="33.5" placeholder="Your message..." name="message" required tabindex="35"></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
   </form>
</div>



  <?php
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $message = $_POST['Message'];
    $from = 'From: mywebsite.com'; 
    $to = 'sk@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from MyWebsite';

    $headers = 'From: mywebsite.com' . "\r\n" . 
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


    $body = "Name: $name\n Email: $email\n Message:\n $message";

?>

//please refer to my PHP code below that communicates with my HTML file.
currently after PHP submits my form it redirects to the homepage. I want
```

it to stay on same page and display Message sent Successfully in the send button.

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 

        header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com");


    } else { 
        echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.</p>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution requies JQuery to run!

```js
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
//DO YOUR STUFF
e.preventDefault()//Remove this line if you want to submit the form
$('#send').hide();
$('.success').show();
});
```

```html
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<div class="form-popup">

        <form id="myForm" action="action_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-container">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="33.5" placeholder="Your message..." name="message" required tabindex="35"></textarea>

  <div class="success" style="display:none;">
      SUCCESS MESSAGE
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
      <button type="submit" class="btn" id="send">Send</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE for author:

```
 <div class="form-popup">

        <form id="myForm" action="action_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-container">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="33.5" placeholder="Your message..." name="message" required tabindex="35"></textarea>

  <div class="success" style="display:none;">
  SUCCESS MESSAGE
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="send">Send</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

 <script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
 <script>
        $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
        //DO YOUR STUFF
        e.preventDefault()//Remove this line if you want to submit the form
        $('#send').hide();
        $('.success').show();
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: I also have a php code. Should I keep it and add the code you gave me in the html file?

Comment: PHP is executed on the server side. JS is executed on the client side. just add <script src="htt(REMOVE THIS)ps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and then <script>$('#myForm').sub.......</script>

Comment: I added your JS script to my HTML. it did not work.

Comment: one question though. The success message is displaying correctly but it not sending the form. do I need to adjust anything in how HTML communicates with PHP? At the moment my PHP is echo to direct to homepage when message sent.

Comment: You should remove e.preventDefault() to submit the form, as commented. Note that the code always displays the success message, it does not actually check whether the sending was successfull or not.

Comment: @TeroLahtinen I removed e.preventDefault()
how to check whether the message sent or not?
once send button is clicked i want the php file to send the form and display the message "Message Sent Successfully" in the same page instead of redirecting to homepage again as the case in my php file at the moment. 

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 

        header("Location: http://www.test.com");

Comment: Please attach your php script, and url your form is located. You should use php to reach the result you want.

Comment: @НадильКаримов I added my PHP code to my HTML code on top. Please check for reference to advise. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should place php code above html and check if the request is POST or GET. the header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com"); is redirecting to the home page. Instead of that create the variable that storing message(success or error) and if the request is POST show it on your form

```html
<?php
$showMsg = false;
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $message = $_POST['Message'];
    $from = 'From: mywebsite.com'; 
    $to = 'sk@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from MyWebsite';

    $headers = 'From: mywebsite.com' . "\r\n" . 
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


    $body = "Name: $name\n Email: $email\n Message:\n $message";
   if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 


    $showMsg = "SUCCESS";


 } else { 
     $showMsg = "ERROR";
    }
 }
    
?>
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
   <form id="myForm" action="action_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-container">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="33.5" placeholder="Your message..." name="message" required tabindex="35"></textarea>
 <?php if( $showMsg) {?> 
     <?= $showMsg ?> 
 <?php } else { ?>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
 <?php } ?>
      <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry i did not understand your point. i placed all the code you gave me up there and it did not work.